# Open source tools for Oracle schema compares

Tags: oracle, schema, migration, ddl, deployment

I'm looking for an open source tool to generate DDL scripts.  Many tools call these synchronization scripts.  We essentially want to compare schema of different environments (ie: DEV to QA, QA to PROD) to manage object migrations/deployments a little easier.  Do open source tools exist like this for Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I work for Red Gate.

Another tool that you may want to consider is Red Gate's [Schema Compare for Oracle](http://www.red-gate.com/schema-compare-for-oracle), which you can use to see a side-by-side view of schema differences and generate upgrade scripts. You can also carry out these tasks via the command line.

It's worth noting that Schema Compare for Oracle has been designed specifically for this task and we focus on making the tool fast, easy to use and accurate. But please don't just take my word for it: [Schema Compare for Oracle reviews](http://www.red-gate.com/products/oracle-development/schema-compare-for-oracle/reviews).

Comment: I tested the tools from the answers and this one seems the best to use.

Answer (score 5):

You might want to have a look at Liquibase - according to the [Liquibase documentation](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/diff.html), it can perform diffs (I'm not 100% sure whether this requires using Liquibase to version your schemas, though).

Comment: Liquibase diff does not require the database to be under version control.

Answer (score 4):

Try SchemaCrawler. It's open source and available on [SourceForge](http://schemacrawler.sourceforge.net/index.html).

I've got some simple instructions to demonstrate it in my blog 
https://gilesey.wordpress.com/2012/11/15/a-lightweight-schema-diff-or-dump-from-oracle/

Answer (score 3):

Not open source, but free to use is Oracle SQL Developer.

At least since version 3.2 Oracle SQL developer contains tools to export a DDL (Database Export) and also to compare databases (Database Diff).

Latest version can be downloaded here: [Oracle SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html)

Comment: Apparently, this requires the Oracle Change Management license, even though the tool is free to use.